# Sessão PHP não funciona

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema do qual uso sessão para validar o usuário. Para validação uso o código abaixo:

```
<?php
session_start();
 public function validaUsuarios($loginUsuario,$senhaUsuario){
       .......
       $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
        header('location: entrar.php');
......
?>
```

E na página entrar.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logado'] == false || $_SESSION['logado'] == ''){
    header('location: index.php');
}else{
 ...........
```

O que não estou entendendo é que em outros servidores funcionava perfeitamente, porém nesse servidor não pega logo de primeira, ou seja, ao dar um print, não passa nenhum valor na sessão.

Comment: A função `validaUsuarios` está dentro de uma classe?

Comment: Sim. Está dentro de uma classe e no topo coloquei session_start().
<?php
session_start();
class Metodos extends Conecta{

Comment: o que acho estranho é que ele retorna para a página de login e quando me logo novamente, ele "enxerga" o valor e consigo acessar.

Comment: Tente colocar `exit();` abaixo dos redirecionamentos. Por exemplo: `header('location: entrar.php'); exit();`

Comment: Coloquei, mas não funcionou. A sessão continua não pegando o valor logo de primeira, só na segunda vez....

Comment: Tenta ver o conteúdo do `$_SESSION `logo depois da linha `$_SESSION['logado'] = true;` pra ver se ta setando na sessão. ex.: `var_dump($_SESSION);die;` Talvez o problema não esteja no pedaço do código que postou.

Comment: Fiz do jeito que vc pediu e aparece os valores, ou seja, o valor é criado, mas quando chega na outra página, o valor chegar vazio.

Comment: Eu diria que tem algo a ver com o handler de erros. Tente trocando o `if($_SESSION['logado'] == false || $_SESSION['logado'] == ''){` por `if(isset($_SESSION['logado']) === false){` pois na verdade, no primeiro momento não existe o index 'logado' e seu server pode estar retornando um warning e não false ou vazio.

Comment: Olá Gê. O problema é que na página de direcionamento não chega nenhum valor na $_SESSION['logado'], ou seja, quando faço a validação o valor aparece como 1, mas quando chega na página que é direcionada, o valor chega vazio.

Comment: Crie um arquivo phpinfo.php, coloque o código <?php phpinfo(); ?> salva o retorno e coloque em algum lugar para podermos analisar.

Comment: Se possível envie de um servidor que funciona e de um que não funciona, pode ser que seja alguma configuração no servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se você tem permissão de escrita na pasta tmp, ou em outra pasta na qual o php está configurado para salvar os arquivos de sessão;

Em todo caso, verifique as configurações do php.ini do servidor e tente forçar configurações usando o ini_set. As possíveis configurações para sessões você pode encontrar em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Prezados, passei por um perrengue parecido com minha aplicação hospedada na LocaWeb, o suporte não ajudou muito, enviei o exemplo abaixo pra eles e me retornaram um outro exemplo, usando formulário (html) e passando o valor via post para uma sessão, em seguida enviando para outra página... enfim, não tinha como usar dessa metodologia toda vez que tivesse que trabalhar com as sessões, e usando meu método as minhas sessões deixavam de existir na pg2.php.
Tinha a seguinte estrutura de teste no domínio:

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["texto"] = "teste";
    echo "<a href=\"pg2.php\">clique aqui</a>";
?>
```

pg2.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo $teste = $_SESSION["texto"];
?>
```

A solução que encontrei foi...
Alterar o caminho da session.save_path no php.ini; e
Ativar o buffer de saída ob_start();

A estrutura passou a ser essa:
index.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["texto"] = "teste";
    echo "<a href=\"pg2.php\">clique aqui</a>";
?>
```

pg2.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    echo $teste = $_SESSION["texto"];
?>
```